# (HELP) React Native JSON File too big. Bundler Heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, babeljs

Firstly, thanks for spending the time to open this and read this. So!
I need to point out that i've just started react native 4 weeks ago from react web development.

Basically i'm making an app where i need to import a pretty big JSON file called 'cityData.json' with the size of around 23.8MB.

Here's an example code of me requiring the JSON.

```
const cityData = require('./dataFolder/cityData.json');
```

and one element of the JSON array looks like this...

```
{ "id": 707860, "name": "Hurzuf", "country": "UA", "coord": { "lon": 34.283333, "lat": 44.549999 } },
```

and there are plenty of these elements.
And whenever i run the code using react-native run-android, i get a memory issue from the bundler.

Heres a screenshot of what it looks like...

[Node terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94YIv.png)

I spent around 3 hours searching why this was happening, and alot of people suggested something about how something shouldn't be transpiled? Something about transforming? Sorry like i said i'm a newbie. They then recommended that i "ignore": the bundle from interacting with my JSON file using .babelrc or package.json? I'm not exactly sure about what they mean about that. I don't get the **/*.js syntax. But i do know for a fact, that whenever i pass in smaller JSON files, it loads perfectly. It's just this JSON file that's wayyy to big! That progress bar just won't move...

As you can see after reading that paragraph, i'm really bad with anything to do with babel and bundles. So hopefully, you guys (who are much more experienced than me) can help me with this!

Note: I have tried adding "Ignore" to both package.json and .babelrc file but i'm pretty sure i did it very wrong.

Thanks for reading and I hope we solve it!

Answer (score 1):

Add `<application android:largeHeap="true" ...>` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response! But when you mention AndroidManifest.xml, which one? i searched for AndroidManifest within my app directory and there are plenty of AndroidManifest.xmls. Is it the one in /phoneApp/android/app/src/main ? Just a side note, i'm building my app with create-react-native-app not react-native init

Comment: I tried to add the android:largeHeap="true" within the androidmanifest application tag but it didn't solve the error :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this JSON reader, it will provide you with JSON elements in callbacks

https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-json-reader